# Can a web browser client connect directly to a remote websocket server?

Tags: websocket

Assuming I have an apache server with an html page, can I include javascript on that html page that attempts to connect to `ws://remote-server.com:24325' to receive messages from the remote host? Most examples I see online are having html pages with javascript that connect to a localhost websocket server like: ws://localhost:24325

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Javascript in your page to connect to a remote server via a webSocket connection.  That's what the webSocket functionality built into a browser is for.

The `localhost` examples you see are probably just examples for local development testing.

Of course, in order to connect to a given host, that host must be running a webSocket server and be accepting incoming connections.

Comment: Websockets are not limited by the SOP. A websocket can connect anywhere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#WebSockets

Comment: By default there is no such limitation. The server has to explicitly forbid connections from unrecognized domains in the "Origin" header. SOP and CORS do not apply here.